# Faster way to do "if" Statements

Tags: c#, winforms, if-statement

Is there faster way to do this? I have 36 different pictures, when the picture changes, i have a string that tracks the image (rotation), image1 is rotation = 1 and so on, what i have to do is use 36 if statements like this:

```
if (rotation == 1) //This is picture1
{

}
else if (rotation == 2) //This is picture2
{

}
```

all the way up to:

```
else if (rotation == 36) //This is picture36
{

}
```

Is there any way figure out what rotation it is with only like 1 or 2 lines of code?
And any who would say check before you ask, i have checked and i found nothing that would help, if you found something, please post it here.

The inside of my if statements are just for changing the image.

Thanks.

Comment: pls show what's inside one of your if...

Comment: Create an array and use `rotation` to index it.

Comment: As Raphael said it all depends what is in your if blocks.  If you are just indexing a picture in David's suggestion works.  If you are creating HTML then your image file name could be myimage_{rotation}.jpg.  In any case, you want to make that rotation some sort of index.

Comment: My problem is that lets say the image is image1, if i press the button to the right of the `PictureBox`, it shows image2 but if i press the button to the left of the `PictureBox`, it shows image36, so i couldn't do like that zam664 said about naming my image the rotation.

Comment: Just store the images in a collection, such as an array (`Image[] images`), and keep track of the current index (`i`). When a button is clicked, increment/decrement `i` then display `images[i]` in the `PictureBox`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Either use an array

```
picture = img[i];
```

or perhaps actually *name* the image after the index (e.g. `image01.jpg`, `image02.jpg` etc.)

The array strikes me as the most extensible and concise solution.

Answer (score 2):

For example say inside your if you print your rotation.

```
if (rotation == 1) //This is picture1
{
   System.out.println(1);
}
else if (rotation == 2) //This is picture2
{
    System.out.println(2);
}


else if(rotation==36)
{
    System.out.println(36);
}
```

You can change the whole code to just one line.

```
System.out.println(rotation);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use an array of `WhateverYourPictureClassIs`, or an `IDictionary<int,WhateverYourPictureClassIs>`, or a `switch` statement.

For instance, if the picture information is a string:

```
string[] pictures = {
  "you might have a blank entry here if the first number is 1 instead of 0",
  "picture1",
  "picture2",
  "picture3",
  "picture4",
  // ...and so on...
};
```

Then looking up the picture is

```
if (picture >= 0 && picture < pictures.Length) { // The 0 might be 1 in your case
    pictureInfo = pictures[picture];
}
```

Or

```
IDictionary<int,string> pictures = new Dictionary<int,string>();
pictures.Add(1, "picture1");
// ...and so on...
```

Looking it up looks much the same.

Or

```
switch (picture) {
    case 1: pictureInfo = "picture1"; break;
    case 2: pictureInfo = "picture2"; break;
    // ...and so on...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This is a long shot and I have an assumptions that name of the images file will always be corresponding to rotation value as shown below

rotation = 1 -----> filename = image1.png
rotation = 2 -----> filename = image2.png

If so you can do this

```
string fileName = "image" + rotation + ".png";
```

You can use this to select or display your file in the way you need.

Answer (score 0):

A switch statement.

http://www.dotnetperls.com/if-switch-performance

```
switch(number)
{
  case 1:

    break;
}
```

Or if you have where you have a `List<T>` - in this case `T` is your picture you can do

```
List<T> pictures = new List<T>();
T picture = pictures[rotation];
```

Comment: @RaphaëlAlthaus the user asked for a faster way to do if statements. My answer is a faster way, even if the benefit is poor. Regardless, I have posted the better option of doing this...

Answer (score 0):

The best way would be to use an int instead of a String, then you can use `switch case`.

Java 7 allows to use Strings in switch statements, I don't know if it's possible in C#.